# _tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display ":0"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, raspberry-pi3

I am working on Raspberry pi model 3 B, i have made a GUI program in python using tkinter and i want to run it on xpt2046 3.2 inches touch screen and i want my program to run on boot.
So first when i tried it to run on my touch screen, it gave me error of DISPLAY variable is empty, so for this i have given the DISPLAY environment variable a value of :0, in `/.bashrc` file. But now I am getting this error on my boot, but if i manually give the command

```
python3 /home/pi/gui.pi
```

the program runs properly.

My `/.bashrc` file includes :

```
export DISPLAY=:0

echo Running at boot

sudo python3 /home/pi/gui.py
```

Answer (score 0):

If I remove `sudo` from`sudo python3 /home/pi/gui.py` then it works without any error.